# In Python, how can I use a function's return statement within a second function without using global variables?

Tags: python, variables, global

I'm working on an assignment in which the constraints specify that I cannot use global variables. Variables are only defined for the specific function. I'm wondering if there is a way to take what a function returns (a string) and then create a new function that can use that string, without global variables? Note: I CAN use variables, just not globals. Thanks!

Per request, here is an example.

```
def func1():
     return "output"
def func2():
     #loop over the string "output",just for example
```

Comment: Can you give a code or pseudocode example? I'm not clear on what you're asking for, or even how much you understand about it.

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> def a():
...     return 'x'
... 
>>> def b(s):
...     print 'b recieved', s
... 
>>> b(a())
b recieved x
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not pass the variable to the new function as a parameter?

e.g.

```
s = someFunc1()

someFunc2(s)
```

Comment: Wouldn't $s still have to be global to be recognized by the second function?

Comment: @nejinx:  I suspect your answer is not in Python.

Comment: Python doesn't use dollar signs or semicolons (at least not the way you're using them).

Comment: Edited to remove dollar/semicolons